# How to setup Asp.net Core TestServer with Azure Function v4 for Integration Tests

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-functions, integration-testing

Trying to setup TestServer form Asp.Net Core manually because WebApplicationFactory is not available for Azure functions. This is for Integration tests in memory.

I have created my own Startup for Integration testing  where I use Sqllite in memory to test services and repositories.

Which works fine, but I want to be able to use TestServer from Asp.Net Core into Azure Functions, tried to Setup using, but throws an exception if I use ConfigureWebHost and ConfigureServices:

System.ObjectDisposedException : Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'IServiceProvider'.

```
ConfigureWebHost((webBuilder) =>
{
    webBuilder.UseTestServer();
})
```

```
    public BaseIntegrationTest()
    {
        TestHost = CreateHostBuilder().Build();
        Task.Run(() => TestHost.RunAsync());
    }

    public IHost TestHost { get; }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args = null) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((services) =>
            {
                services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

                services.AddDomain();

                services.AddDbContext<HubDbContext>(options
                    => options.UseSqlite("Filename=:memory:",
                        (options) =>
                        {
                        }));

                services.AddRepositories();
            });
```

Comment: try check whether the Testhost is disposed or not? then move further

Comment: refer this article on integration test in functions https://saebamini.com/integration-testing-in-azure-functions-with-dependency-injection/